# Convert java Date to a chronologically sortable string?

Tags: java, date

I'm lazy, I know (by hey, at least next time I Google it then I'll find the answer)

Do you have an existing piece of code that takes a Date object, and generates a string, that has a sort order equivalent to the chronological order?

I want the string to contain all the date pieces (day, month, hour, minute, milliseconds, ...) and that when two strings are compared, the string representing the earliest date will be before the string representing the later date.

Comment: Anything to do with Java and Date, I always think its worth recomnending http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/  so much better than the standard lib.

Comment: No.  And I'm too lazy to write one especially for you. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Date[] dates=//....;
List<String> listToSort=new ArrayList<String>(dates.length);
SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS");
for(Date date: dates) {
   String sDate=format.format(date);
   listToSort.add(sDate);
}
Collections.sort(listToSort);
```

I'm lazy too, so maybe it has some compile errors, or not (haven't checked it).

Comment: +1 for laziness! (Actually I just needed the SimpleDateFormat bit to convert one date)

Answer (score 2):

```
java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = 
    new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSSS");
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
// convert to GMT, if needed, look at this
String sortableDate = dateForamt.format(date);
```

Comment: There should only be 3 digits (SSS) for milliseconds at the end: yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS

Answer (score 1):

[ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) defines a set of standard date and time representations that share the following property:

> Date and time values are organized *from the most to the least significant*: year, month (or week), day, hour, minute, second, and fraction of second. The lexicographical order of the representation thus corresponds to chronological order, except for date representations involving negative years.

This means that any ISO 8601 format would be OK for you -- sorting ISO 8601 formatted dates alphabetically is equivalent to sorting them chronologically.

It should not be difficult to format dates in ISO 8601 format, either using `DateFormat` directly, or the powerful [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/index.html) library.